# Using HT12E/D with RX/TX 433Mhz modules

Tags: rf, transmitter, encoder, receiver, decoder

i have ht12d and ht12e ic's and rx tx 433Mhz modules. i arranged the ht12e to the output port of Microcontroller and connected the ht12e to transmitter and similarly to the recieving side. is it now ready to transmit data and recieve data which i send to its pins?My question is; does the ht12e and d automatically sets the baud rate for sending the data to transmitter? Is there any values to be set in the ht12e/d and/or transmitter/reciever before starting it to transmit/recieve? Is it simply like put 4bits in ht12e and collect them from ht12d?

Comment: Just read what you wrote. Pretend someone asked you this question. Do you have enough information to answer it ? I am building my own car. I put the wheels on, and put an engine. Is it ready to drive ?

Comment: my question is; does the ht12e and d automatically sets the baud rate for sending the data to transmitter? Is there any values to be set in the ht12e/d and/or transmitter/reciever before starting it to transmit/recieve? Is it simply like put 4bits in ht12e and collect them from ht12d?

Answer (score 3):

The HT12e (encoder) and HT12d (decoder) are both clocked by internal oscillators whose frequency is controlled by an external resistor. The resistor values should be chosen to match the decoder to the encoder (decoder oscillator frequency = ~50x encoder oscillator frequency). The bits are encoded to a type of [Manchester code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manchester_code), which is self clocking so the frequency can actually vary over a wide range.

The 'baud rate' (bit rate of the Manchester code) is determined by the encoder's oscillator frequency. So long as the decoder's oscillator is running *approximately* 50 times faster it should be able to decode the data correctly. In this sense the 'baud rate' is automatic, and its exact value is unimportant.

The HT12 chipset is designed for use in remote controls that have momentary push-buttons. When the MCU is sending the 4 bits of data, as far as the HT12e is concerned it is just pushing one or more buttons. When the HT12e is active it sends those button states (data inputs) continuously, and the decoder's data outputs follow them.

However the data bits are embedded in a packet which has many other bits (preamble, sync, address etc.) and each packet must be repeated 3 times before the decoder accepts it. Therefore the rate at which the decoder outputs follow the encoder inputs is *much* lower than the 'baud rate' of the encoder. So don't think of it as a serial data link, but 4 MCU output pins whose states are repeated at a remote location.

Comment: thanks. so my questions;
1:If I choose any value resistor (10k suppose) for encoder what value shoud i choose for decoder?
2:Should i dont care about the baud rate, the transmiter/reciever and Enc/Dec are working with?
3:Should I just make the connections and put the data to pins of Encoder and collect it from Decoder after some delay, as you said the pins are remotely controlled pins?
please I am waiting for your answers, simple answers.

Comment: 1. Read the datasheets to see the relationships between resistor value and frequency. 10k is much too low. The recommended value is 1M, which gives a frequency of about 3kHz. The matching decoder value is 51k, giving a frequency of about 150kHz. The decoder frequency should be kept below 300kHz (see http://www.holtek.com/english/tech/faq/212_faq.htm#3-1). 2. Yes 3. Yes.

Comment: thanks i googled it,the transmitter resistor is 1.1M while reciever's is 51k

Comment: i have connected them as you said, itried different resistors but nothing happens. what is wrong.